# GDI+: Calculate intersection with curve

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I've got an array of Point-objects and draw a curve using

```
graphics.Draw(pen, points);
```

What I know need is to somehow calculate the intersection of a line with the drawn curve. Is there any way to do that with GDI+? I couldn't find a function or class.

Thx,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI+ does not contain any geometrical functions that I'm aware of. It is a pure rendering API. You need to handle all the geometrical processing using another library, or write your own such functions. 
Intersecting a line with another line is fairly simple. Intersecting a line with a number of lines is a trivial extension of that (loop over the lines). Let me know if you need pointers to examples.